# escape characters in Swift

Tags: swift, escaping, newline

I specifically am wondering how you could escape a newline in Swift, but generic escape characters would be great too.

In Python you can do this:

```
print("Dear grandma, \nHow are you?")
```

How can you do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines as `\n` work in Swift string literals too.

Check out the docs: [Special Unicode Characters in String Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID295)

Comment: This link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example replacing a unicode character in a string with a comma (to give you a sense of using escaped unicodes).

```
address = address.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{0000200e}", withString: ",", options: nil, range: nil)
```

Comment: would you please give a bit more information on what the arguments in this call do?

Comment: Sure:  here is a reference to the doc for stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:>

In particular, in the example, unicode 0000200e is being replaced with a comma (",").